# Get specific data from firebase

Tags: java, android, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I've a ArrayList which contains specific positions of data on firebase

ArrayList will have values like {3, 36} which are node positions on firebase.

I want to know how can i get data from those specific positions on firebase database and show it in a recyclerView

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate the exact data that you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using a `forEach` loop on that `ArrayList` and fetch the information according to your structure of database, like this:

```
for (int num: arrayList) {
    DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase
        .getInstance()
        .getReference()
        .child("" + num);

    // Fetch data over here
}
```

Now that you have the `reference`, you can fetch the data as per your need, and can add that bit the data to your `ArrayAdapter`.